# Retrieving the cmd line arguments as it is in Python

Tags: python, linux, shell, command-line-arguments

I am writing a wrapper tool in python. Invocation of the tool is as  below:

```
<wrapper program> <actual program>  <arguments>
```

The wrapper program just adds one more argument and executes the actual program:

```
<actual program> <arguments> <additional args added>
```

The tricky part is that  has some strings that are escaped and some are not escaped

```
Example arguments format: -d \"abc\"  -f "xyz"  "pqr" and more args
```

The wrapper tool is generic and it shouldn't  know about the actual program and parameters, other than adding an additional argument

I understand that this is related to the shell. Any suggestions on how to implement the wrapper tool.

I tried implementing by  escaping all the  "". There are some cases in which "" are not escaped in the invocation, so the tool is not able to execute the actual program correctly.

Is it possible to preserve the original arguments as provided by the user ?.

Wrapper.py Source:

```
import sys
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd = sys.argv[1] + " " 
    args = sys.argv[2:]
    args.insert(0, "test")
    cmd_string = cmd + " ".join(args)
    print("Executing:", cmd_string)
    os.system(cmd_string)
```

Output:

```
wrapper.py tool -d "abc" -f \"pqr\" 123
Executing: tool test -d abc -f "pqr" 123
```

Expected execution:  `tool test -d "abc" -f \"pqr\" 123`

Comment: Preserving the original arguments is the default behavior. You don't need to do anything special, assuming you don't use the shell (and why would you?).

Comment: @melpomene: The tools are invoked from the linux shell

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean you have to run another shell from Python. I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: Is it the wrapper program is in Python? If so - how is it that making the call to the actual program and arguments?

Comment: @JonClements: Yes, the wrapper tool  is in Python.

Comment: Right... so are you doing something like: `subprocess.call([sys.argv[1], *sys.argv[1:], 'extra', 'arguments'])` ?

Comment: @melpomene: The wrapper tool get the <actaul program> and <arg> as command line arguments. The tool adds one more argument and invokes the actual program with new set of arguments (using os.system or os.execv) . The issue is since the arguments have some strings that are escaped and some are not. For example  -d "abc" -  ARGV list in wrapper tool will get only abc and not "abc". Similarly  -f  \"abc\" - ARGV list in wrapper tool will get only "abc" and not \"abc\"

Comment: Use subprocess.call like above instead of dealing with strings... then you don't have to worry about escaping stuff...

Comment: Since argv list itself is not having what is required. How will subprocess.call solve it?.

Comment: Can you provide examples... you're saying suggestions won't work but you haven't shown 1) an example call, 2) what your wrapper program receives for it or 3) how you're then attempting to add arguments and call the wrapped program...

Comment: Sure. I'll update the question with these details

Comment: "*-d "abc" - ARGV list in wrapper tool will get only abc*" - yes, that's what's supposed to happen. If you call the original program directly, it will also only see `abc`.

Comment: By the way, doing this with a shell script is trivial: `exec "$@" extra-args-here`. Why use Python at all?

Comment: @melpomene was also wondering that... but was guessing there's something somewhat more complicated going on in the Python wrapper to calculate/retrieve those extra arguments instead of just trying to extend them :)

Comment: `cmd + " ".join(args)` - here's your problem. Don't convert the list of arguments to a string.

Comment: Updated the question with the details and simplistic example There are a bunch of checks to be done, before adding the additional option

Comment: Why is `tool test -d "abc" -f \"pqr\" 123` your expected output... the ""'s in the shell for an argument get removed as they're not part of the argument - just instructions to the shell to parse it a certain way unless you literally escape them to be quote characters as you're doing with the other argument preserving them... But yes... don't deal with strings... use the approach I pointed out above with .call and passing a list of argv elements to it...

Comment: If you create a script (x.py maybe that literally does `import sys; print(sys.argv)`) and try: `python x.py one two three`, `python x.py "one two three"`, `python x.py "\"one two three\""` and `python x.py \"one two three\"` you'll see the differences...

Comment: `os.system()` is a broken API. It takes a single string and launches a new shell process which parses that string back into a list of arguments (for potentially multiple commands), and then executes that. You already have a list of arguments: don't smush them together into a string just to have that string parsed back into a list of arguments -- instead use an API that takes a list of arguments directly. The `subprocess` module has lots of options here and has very good documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `subprocess.call` here and then you're not dealing with strings/having to worry about escaping values etc...

```
import sys
import subprocess
import random

subprocess.call([
    sys.argv[1], # the program to call
    *sys.argv[2:], # the original arguments to pass through
    # do extra args...
    '--some-argument', random.randint(1, 100),
    '--text-argument', 'some string with "quoted stuff"',
    '-o', 'string with no quoted stuff',
    'arg_x',
    'arg_y',
    # etc...
])
```

If you're after getting the stdout of the call then you can do `result = subprocess.check_output(...)` (or also pipe the callees stderr to it as well) if you then want to check results... Note from 3.5 onwards, there's also another high level helper [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) that covers the majority of use cases.

It'll be worth checking out all the helper functions in [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html)